# Android Runnable stop handler after application Resumed

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, handler, runnable, onresume

I have an application which from inside a fragment runs a postDelayed task every 1 second using a handler which is enabled/disabled using a checkbox. (Working fine)

When the app is paused, the runnable still has effect in the background as I want it to. However, If I resume the app, I want to be able to stop the handler if checkBox becomes unChecked using handler.removeCallbacks(runnable) but I get a NullPointerException.

Is there a way to do this?

```js
@Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(checkBox1.isChecked()) {
      if(deviceStart()==0) {
        //Failed to start service
        checkBox1.setChecked(false);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to Start Service. Please Try Again...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } else {
          handler = new Handler();
          handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
      }
    } else {
      if(pocketHaloStop()==0) {
        //Failed to stop service
        checkBox1.setChecked(true);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to Stop Service. Please Try Again...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } else {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable); //This generates Null Pointer Exception if app is Resumed!
      }
    }
  });
```

Here is the code for the Runnable and onPause / onResume:

```js
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
  
  @Override
  public void run() {
   /* do what you need to do */

   handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
  }
 };
    
    private void save(final boolean isChecked) {
  mContext = getActivity();
  SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("Check", isChecked);
  editor.commit();
 }

 private boolean load() { 
  mContext = getActivity();
  SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  return settings.getBoolean("Check", false);
 }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     checkBox1 = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkEnable);
  checkBox1.setChecked(load());
  
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        save(checkBox1.isChecked());
        checkBox1.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
```

Comment: In which line do you get this exception? Post your LogCat pls.

Comment: Hi, I can't post the logcat, we have our own build of android on custom hardware. Ther is a comment at  handler.removeCallbacks(runnable); which says this line generated the exception, Thanks.

Comment: Then show us the Android system functions `onResume` and `onPause` on your codes. And `runnable` is initialized while the app resuming after paused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the creation of the Handler to the onCreate().

```
 ....
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...

     handler = new Handler();

     ...
 }
```

Comment: This seems to get rid of the nullPointer exception, but now handler.removeCallbacks(runnable) does not stop the handler from functioning.

Comment: have you considered using the CountDownTimer (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) it might help you and it is easier to control, making your logic easier.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure this will work. I have a checkBox (In custom settings app) which needs to start a specific task that runs every 1 second. This works (even when paused), but what I cannot do, is re-gain control of the handler after resuming the app.

Comment: In theory as you're creating the handler ONLY from the onCreate() it should remain the same after the onResume() so I don't see why you lose control over it. Try also to move the checkBox1 = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkEnable); to the onCreate().

Comment: but according to your words, if you want to run something regardless if the activity is paused or not..then you're talking about 'Services' http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html this is what you might actually need. It runs even if the activity is paused. You can setup a listener to the 'settings' changed, and according to it, you start or stop the service.